# Vuex getter and array reduce

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to code some getters to calculate a part total and a per item total. But when I refactored the code to use array.reduce, the partTotal returned undefined.

Can you help me to know why this works:

```
getters: {

    calcPart: (state, getters) => part => {

        let total = 0.0

        for (let i = 0, length = part.items.length; i < length; i++) {
            total += getters.calcItem(part.items[i])
        }

        return total

    },

    calcItem: state => item => {
        return parseFloat(item.value1) * parseFloat(item.value2)
    },

}
```

And why this does not work (calcPart returns "undefined"):

```
getters: {

    calcPart: (state, getters) => part => {
        return part.items.reduce((acc, item) => { acc + getters.calcItem(item) }, 0.0)
    },

    calcItem: state => item => {
        return parseFloat(item.value1) * parseFloat(item.value2)
    },

}
```

Has it something to do with the fact of reduce is an async function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return inside braces.

Change this line:

```
return part.items.reduce((acc, item) => { acc + getters.calcItem(item) }, 0.0)
```

To this one:

```
return part.items.reduce((acc, item) => { return acc + getters.calcItem(item) }, 0.0)
```

You can also avoid the undefined result by just removing the braces:

```
return part.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + getters.calcItem(item), 0.0)
```

Side note: Type semicolons.